# Are [vhdl] questions on-topic for Code Review?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

To date, we have had four questions about [VHDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL), a language for describing digital circuits.  Of those questions, one was closed for containing broken code.

Should [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) be considered on-topic or off-topic for Code Review?

On one hand, it does fit within a broad definition of "code", and VHDL code can certainly be reviewed.

On the other hand, it's very low-level code, and there just doesn't seem to be much interest or expertise in the Code Review community to answer these questions.  There are certainly more VHDL experts on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Some possibilities are:

1. Routinely migrate requests to review [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) to EE (on grounds that VHDL is off-topic for CR),
2. Ask authors to repost their questions on EE,
3. Try to entice EE users to try their hand at reviewing [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) here on CR,
4. Do nothing, and let these questions languish here.

Your thoughts?

Comment: It's otherwise on topic, right? We just don't have any reviewers?

Comment: @RubberDuck You could say that. You could also say that it's too low-level to ever attract much interest here.

Comment: [*I don't think it's worth it to establish a policy for every possible odd situation. A mountain of policy just raises the barrier to entry, which is something you don't want for a large collaborative effort.*](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/are-encrypted-answers-acceptable#comment6324_2456) (that said, I agree with Mug's answer)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg If I weren't bound by policy, I probably would have migrated some of these questions to [electronics.se] already. Unlike an answer whose oddity can be edited away, policy does matter here, I think.

Comment: Can you compile and run VHDL, or is it just a syntax for consistency?

Comment: I have asked the moderators on [electronics.se] for their input on this question.

Comment: I vote for 2 & 3

Answer (score 11):

I'd take that bullet list backwards:

> **4. Do nothing, and let these questions languish here.**

Certainly not. That doesn't help anyone.

> **3. Try to entice EE users to try their hand at reviewing [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) here on CR**

With 4 questions in some 18 months since the tag's creation, bringing EE users here is a bit of a stretch. Not impossible, but you'd have to find an EE user that's more into programming, I believe.

> **2. Ask authors to repost their questions on EE**

That sounds more realistic. The question isn't off-topic on CR, it's just that Stack Exchange happens to have a more specialized site where [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) might have a wider audience. I don't see cross-posting as a problem. Unless...

> **1. Routinely migrate requests to review [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) to EE (on grounds that VHDL is off-topic for CR)**

Off-topic... but on what grounds? I know nothing about it, but VHDL sure looks like code to me. Not to [cite Wikipedia as an authoritative source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17572563#17572563), but...

> *Due to the Department of Defense requiring as much of the syntax as possible to be based on Ada, in order to avoid re-inventing concepts that had already been thoroughly tested in the development of Ada,<sup>[citation needed]</sup> VHDL borrows heavily from the Ada programming language in both concepts and syntax.*
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL</sub>

And

> *Ada is a structured, statically typed, imperative, wide-spectrum, and object-oriented high-level computer programming language, extended from Pascal and other languages.*
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)</sub>

Looks like a programming language to me, and a useful one on top of it. I think considering it off-topic *just because we don't have the expertise* is fraying with a slippery slope. Would [php](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) be off-topic if there weren't enough reviewers for it?

---

I vote for #2 (cross-posting), and if people there start sending [vhdl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) askers over here, then they'll <s>inevitably</s> *hopefully* bring some reviewers along with these questions. Perhaps some of these reviewers know some [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), too. At the end of the day, it's about visibility / getting the right eyes on the piece of code.